# Disable Apache welcome page for only specific virtual hosts?

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

Running Centos 7 w/ Apache 2.4.  Setting up a repository with a virtual host which I want to be able to display non-`index.html` files and directories in the document root directory.  But when I access it in a browser, I get the Apache testing page.  So, I look at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` and see that all I need to do is comment out all the lines (tested it and it works as advertised).  But I want to keep this functionality on all sites, just not on this single virtual host.

How do I disable the welcome page on a per virtual host basis?

```
[michael@mybox main]$ cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf
#
# This configuration file enables the default "Welcome" page if there
# is no default index page present for the root URL.  To disable the
# Welcome page, comment out all the lines below.
#
# NOTE: if this file is removed, it will be restored on upgrades.
#
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
</LocationMatch>

<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
Alias /noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css
Alias /noindex/css/open-sans.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/open-sans.css
Alias /images/apache_pb.gif /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/apache_pb.gif
Alias /images/poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/poweredby.png
[michael@mybox main]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override it in the appropriate virtual host

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options +Indexes
</LocationMatch>
```